# CSS variables in Firefox's userChrome.css do not take effect

Tags: css, firefox, css-variables, userchrome.css

I'm using Firefox 72 on FreeBSD and configure some style in `userChrome.css`. This works fine. As an example, I can make the label of the "File" menu in the menu bar red with

```css
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");
#file-menu {
   color: red !important;
}
```

Now I heard of the new-fangled (not so much anymore, it would seem) *CSS variable*, aka *CSS property `--*`*, and tried to use them. Alas, I must be missing something because this:

```css
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");
:root {
   --foo: red;
}
#file-menu {
   color: var(--foo) !important;
}
```

leaves "File" at the default color, black. Should this work? Am I missing something? After some searching I found that in `about:config` the value for `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` should be `true`, which it is. Now I'm out of ideas.

Comment: and if you try like this `#file-menu {
   --foo:red;color: var(--foo) !important;
}` ? maybe there is an issue with the root selector. I know it's useless but to identify the *root* problem

Comment: @TemaniAfif Interestingly, your suggestion *does* work! So it seems to be in fact a problem with the scope of `:root`.

Comment: then try `html {--foo:red}`, technically it's the same as using `:root`. Maybe for some reason you don't have to use `:root`

Comment: Using `html` has the same problem. In my desperation I removed the `@namespace` line, and then everything works! With either `:root` or `html`. The default `userChrome.css` file always warned not to remove it. Looks like this has changed over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the `@namespace` line. After deleting it, the CSS variables work.

Comment: yeah, this is something new in FF 72 -- that @namespace line had to be there before that -- no need to downvote the question, it is legit.